# Need help creating structure.sql for my Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to manually create/update the db/structure.sql file for test purposes. I have "`config.active_record.schema_format = :sql`" set in application.rb. I am wondering if there is a command equivalent to "`ActiveRecord::SchemaDumper.dump`" that will create or update structure.sql. I've tried structure_dump, but the output is nil:

```
> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.structure_dump
=> nil
```

I also tried passing a file to that method:

```
> File.open( File.join(Rails.root, 'db/structure.sql')) { |f| ActiveRecord::Base.connection.structure_dump() }
 => nil
```

So far, the only way I've been able to generate or update db/structure.sql is by running rake db:migrate. Any alternatives? Or am I missing something when trying to run ActiveRecord::Base.connection.structure_dump?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Try `rake db:structure:dump` which will recreate the `db/structure.sql` from the database.

For the latest versions of rails the command `rake db:schema:dump` works with `db/structure.sql` too.

Comment: `rake db:schema:dump` just regenerates schema.rb. I'm trying to get structure.sql.

Comment: my bad. forgot that you're using sql format. see the updated answer

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm actually wondering if there is a non-rake task way of doing it, just because I'll be calling it from a test, and calling the rake task seems like it shouldn't be necessary (although I am pretty new to Rails, so I may presume too much). I was thinking that if ActiveRecord::SchemaDumper.dump is the command equivalent of rake db:schema:dump, maybe there is a similar one-line equivalent to rake db:structure:dump...?

Comment: why are you calling it in a test?

Comment: We have a migrations spec that verifies that the schema is up-to-date and has been committed.  We're switching over to using structure.sql instead of schema.rb, so I'm trying to fix this method:      `def schema_dump
  File.open( File.join(Rails.root, 'db/schema.rb'), 'w' ) do |stream|
      ActiveRecord::SchemaDumper.dump(ActiveRecord::Base.connection, stream)
    end
  end`